# If $\not\exists r+I$ nilpotent then $R/I$ is an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, nilpotence

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $I$ an ideal of $R$.

Definition: a non zero element $ a\in R$ is nilpotent if $\exists n\in\Bbb N$ s.t. $a^n=0$

It is true that if $R/I$ is an integral domain then there cannot be any nilpotent element in $R/I$. But is the other way also true?

Comment: Probably you want to add $a \neq 0$ to the definition of nilpotent.

Comment: I zero generally not considered nilpotent then?

Comment: I take my comment back, at least in the Wikipedia $0$ is nilpotent. Then the statement of the theorem should be that if $R/I$ is an integral domain, there is no nonzero nilpotent element in $R/I$. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

A ring is called [reduced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_ring) if the only nilpotent element is $0$.

Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring. Just as $R/I$ is an integral domain iff $I$ is a prime ideal, there is an analogous result that $R/I$ is a reduced ring iff $I$ is a radical ideal, that is, $\sqrt{I}=I$, where $\sqrt{I}=\{x\in R\mid x^n\in I \text{ for some } n\in\mathbb N\}$.

It is obvious that "domain implies reduced," but there are obviously rings which are reduced but which are not domains. In such rings the zero ideal serves as a counterexample to "the other way" you are asking about.

Here is a [DaRT search](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=10&L=8) for reduced rings that aren't domains. Keep in mind this list may include noncommutative examples.

Comment: To provide an example of such  ring, $R= \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ works

Comment: @Max That is captured by one of the examples given in the link: $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, $n$ a squarefree composite number.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't seen the link, my bad !

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $I$ be the ideal $(6)$ in the ring $R = \mathbb{Z}$. More generally, for an ideal $I = (n)$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ where $n \neq 0, 1$, there are nilpotents in $\mathbb{Z}/I$ whenever $(n)$ has some prime power in its factorization, and there are zero-divisors whenever $(n)$ is not prime.